# Is wi-fi synchronous or asynchronous

Tags: wireless-networking

Can a computer send a bit through wi-fi to 2 different IPs at the exact same time, or is it asynchronous? And if the former, how many channels do most computers have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wi-Fi is asynchronous, but not in the way you seem to be trying to use the term. When speaking of technologies for communication between computers, "synchronous" means the two computers share a clock signal (such as via a clock pin of a multi-pin serial interface), whereas "asynchronous" means they do not share a clock signal.

Wi-Fi does not involve a shared clock signal, so it is asynchronous.

As for your question about sending bits or packets to two different devices or IP addresses at the same time:

Starting with 802.11ac (a.k.a. "AC", "Wi-Fi 5"), Wi-Fi has had provisions for an AP (wireless router) to send multiple packets simultaneously to separate devices. AC used a technology called "downlink MU-MIMO" for this. AX (802.11ax, "Wi-Fi 6", "Wi-Fi 6E") added a second way to do this, called OFDMA. However, neither MU-MIMO (including both downlink and uplink MU-MIMO) nor OFDMA allow a single Wi-Fi client device (a non-AP device) to send multiple packets truly simultaneously. Since 802.11n in 2007, and honestly since about 2003 using nonstandard tricks that were revised and standardized in 802.11n, devices have been able to send multiple packets to multiple destinations back-to-back in a single burst or "aggregate frame", in a single transmit operation (TXOP).

APs supporting downlink MU-MIMO can send one packet per spatial stream. So a 4x4:4 AP can send 4 packets simultaneously. This would require that all four client devices also support MU-MIMO so they know how to understand such a transmission.

APs supporting OFDMA with 160MHz-wide channels (or 80+80) could conceivably send 74 packets to 74 different devices simultaneously. Again, you'd need 74 clients, all supporting OFDMA and 160MHz-wide channels, associated to a single AP that also supports those things.

Comment: Also, broadcast or multicast frames are received by multiple stations simultaneously.

Comment: @Zac67 I felt like OP took pains to make clear that he was talking about multiple simultaneous unicasts, even though he didn't know the right jargon to use.